# Issue with using namespaces and assembly definitions in a Unity3D project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 5 scripts in the same folder which all reference my main `PlayerMovement` script. In the Unity project settings I set my root namespace already to `ExampleNamespace` and then in my `PlayerMovement` script I wrapped all my code around `namespace ExampleNamespace {}`.

But then I got the error:

> Type or namespace "PlayerMovement" could not be found

and the error appears on those 5 scripts above which all reference my `PlayerMovement` script.

At the top of each of those scripts I added `using ExampleNamespace;` and the errors all disappeared. But when I was looking at multiple tutorials on namespaces I saw that instead of `using ExampleNamespace;`, all of the relevant scripts were wrapped in `namespace ExampleNameSpace {}` so I'm a bit confused and I'm not sure if one of the approaches is better than the other.

I also created a new Assembly Definition and just placed it where all my scripts are located and left it as default. From what I understand, if I create another folder which contains other non-PlayerMovement related scripts like for UI or interactables, then I would create another separate Assembly Definition and create a new namespace for that folder?

Comment: well, if you're other scripts arent in the same name space, and you left the default name space as is, it will not include your new namespace, you would need to add it. You didnt mention adding the other scripts to the same name space

Comment: But for now since I only have one namespace, I can just wrap `nameSpace ExampleNameSpace {}` around every script right and that's it? And then include an Assembly Defintion for that particular namespace

Comment: the assembly definition might not gain you a lot, but yes, if they are all in the same name space, you should be ok.